# Using the same code with different definitions of structures

Tags: c, structure, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, typedef

I have a function that traverses a binary search tree
`traverse(node_t*)`, where:

```
typedef struct node_t{
    char *key;
    char *item;
    struct node_t *parent;
    struct node_t *left;
    struct node_t *right;
}node_t;
```

Would I be able to use the same function `traverse(node_t*)` with a *different* structure under the same identifier by doing something to the header file?
e.g. a different structure such as:

```
typedef struct node_t{
    char *key;
    char *item;
    struct node_t *parent;
    struct node_t *left;
    struct node_t *right;
    struct node_t *next;
}node_t;
```

where I've simply added a member to the structure that wouldn't be accessed in the function anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Of course the functions have to have different names to be able to distinguish them, so you need some macro trickery. Check the linux kernel source for some ideas.

Comment: C does not allow overloading or inheritance. However, if you move the data fields past the management fields, you can write generic functions which only operate on the management fields. Drawback is you have to  cast the actual types lateron.

Comment: You should never have two different declarations of the same structure.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same function"?

Comment: You're treading on thin ice.  If you tried to treat a pointer to the structure as part of an array (so you added one to the pointer, or used a non-zero subscript), then you'd be broken — the increments would be wrong for one structure or the other.  If you only access the common fields and they're defined the same, you can get away with it (in practice), but you're playing with fire — expect to get burnt sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not recommended.

First, you could achieve this if you include one and only one of the files that define the tree structure. The easiest way to do this is to define some kind of dummy preprocessor constant that defines which file to include. E.g.:

```
#define INCLUDE_TREE_WITH_PARENT
#ifdef INCLUDE_TREE_WITH_PARENT
  #include "tree_with_parent.h"
#else INCLUDE_TREE_WITH_PARENT
  #include "tree.h"
#end
```

However, you can only use fields that are common to both types of trees in your function, because if you use a field that is not defined in the type you included, the code would not even compile.

This is very tricky and can confuse anyone who is reading your code, since this kind of "template" programming is not common for C.